# Getting IOS parse payload data when app icon in home screen clicked

Tags: ios, iphone, qt, parse-platform

I am working on parse push messages on iOS device.I was able to integrate the whole push functionality and its working fine.The only problem which I am facing is, how can I get the Parse Push payload data by clicking on the app icon on the home screen (when the app is in background or inactive) when a Push Notification is received on the device?

Answer (score 1):

From the [Apple Local and Remote Notification Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW4)

> If the app icon is clicked on a computer running OS X, the app calls the delegate’s `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` method in which the delegate can obtain the remote-notification payload. If the app icon is tapped on a device running iOS, the app calls the same method, but furnishes no information about the notification.

So, in summary, if the user doesn't action your remote notification you don't get any details of the push message.

The guide also says

> Although you may define custom properties for the payload, you should
>   never use the remote-notification mechanism for data transport because
>   delivery of remote notifications is not guaranteed.

Comment: Thanks paulw11 for your comment.So i have to find a way to get my payload when the app icon is clicked.

Comment: Yes, when your app launches you should fetch any new data - the notification acts as a prompt to the user that there is new data available but can't be the only method of delivering that data.  You can also use "silent push" to notify your app that there is new data, but again delivery isn't guaranteed so you should always back it up with a check when your app launches